# How to display number of epochs in tensorflow object detection api with Faster Rcnn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow Object detection api. What I understood reading the **faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config** file is that num_steps mean the total number of steps and not the epochs. But then what is the point of specifying batch_size?? Lets say I have 500 images in my training data and I set batch size = 5 and num_steps = 20k. Does that mean number of epochs are equal to 200 ??

When I run model_main.py it shows only the global_steps loss. So if these global steps are not the epochs then **how should I change the code to display train loss and val loss after each step and also after each epoch.**

Comment: how did you come up with 200 epochs? thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you are right with your assumption, that you have 200 epochs.

I had a similar problem with the not showing of loss.
my solution was to go to the model_main.py file and then insert

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

after the import stuff.
then it shows you the loss after each 100 steps.
you could change the set_verbosity if you want to have it after every epoch ;)

Comment: Actually I wanted to know how to display train and val loss after each step. Also since I have set evaluation after 100 steps so it wont evaluate after each step. So one solution is to set evaluation after each step and for this need to specify the correct batch size in eval config. Do you have a better solution as this one would make my training very slow.